# How attach a click event with chaining method JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

How does the click event work in JQuery?

I mean, I learned how to make chaining method but I have no idea of how make the click event like this:

```
MyLibrary("selector").click(function(){
console.log("hello");
});
```

I guest that if I learned this, i'll know how does `blur`, `mouseover`, etc etc, works as well.

Please I hope you help me learn, I searched for answer but i could not find any or maybe I was asking in the wrong way.

**UPDATE**

I know how to use jQuery, **BUT WHAT I ASKED WAS** how can I make it? I mean, I want to create a library and I want to add a click event like jQuery does.

I did chaining method like this:

```
Find().UserByName("Bob").Write("DivOrInputObject's ID").UserByPass("pass").Write("DivOrInputObject's ID");
```

But while writing the code, It came to my mind how can I make a click event? In simple words, I want to imitate `click()` event like jQuery does and add it to my library.

Comment: I believe the jQuery doc's can help --> http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery

Comment: What does `MyLibrary("selector")` return? Are you sure you don't want to use `$("selector")`?

Comment: `MyLibrary("selector")` must return jQuery collection object for this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you are writing your own jQuery. So if your MyLibrary object have selected element under MyLibrary.el then you can have chainable click handler like this:

```
click: function(handler){
  this.el.addEventListener('click', handler.bind(this.el));
  return this;
},
```

This will bind `this` inside the handler to the element itself. Just like jQuery

Here is this code in action: http://jsbin.com/ahinow/1/

Comment: Sorry it I bother you, can you give an example like printing a Hello world message when i click in a bottom??